# Untar only a certain number of files from a large tarball

Tags: tar

I have a large tarball that is busy being FTP'd over from a remote system to our local system.

I want to know if it is possible to start untarring lets say 50 files at a time so that those files can begin being processed while the transfer takes place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-extracting-specific-files/) is a detailed explanation on how it is possible to extract specific files from an archive. Specifically GNU tar can be used to extract a single or more files from a tarball. To extract specific archive members, give their exact member names as arguments.

For example:

```
tar --extract --file={tarball.tar} {file}
```

You can also extract those files that match a specific globbing pattern (wildcards). For example, to extract from cbz.tar all files that begin with pic, no matter their directory prefix, you could type:

```
tar -xf cbz.tar --wildcards --no-anchored 'pic*'
```

To extract all php files, enter:

```
tar -xf cbz.tar --wildcards --no-anchored '*.php'
```

Where,

`-x`: instructs tar to extract files.
`-f`: specifies filename / tarball name.
`-v`: Verbose (show progress while extracting files).
`-j`: filter archive through bzip2, use to decompress .bz2 files.
`-z`: filter archive through gzip, use to decompress .gz files.
`--wildcards`: instructs tar to treat command line arguments as globbing patterns.
`--no-anchored`: informs it that the patterns apply to member names after any / delimiter.

Comment: I don't want to extract specific files. I just want to extract the first 50 files as I don't know what the names of the files are.

Comment: You can get a list of the filenames using "tar -tf", take the first 50 using "head", then feed that list into another tar command as the list of filenames to extract. Like this: "tar -xf file.tar --no-anchored \`tar -tf file.tar|head -50\`"

Comment: It is quite possible (in my testing) to extract a partially trandferred 50th file.. It would be a good idea to avoid extracting the (current) last file in the `-t` list until the tarball is fully downloaded. At any point of time, the list shows only filenames which have been, or are being, transferred, ie. not the *full* list; until it is fully downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
tar -tvf tarfile.tar
```

gives you the whole list of files in `tarfile.tar`

```
tar -xvf tarfile.tar fileToRestore
```

This command restores the `fileToRestore`

To untar multiple files, but not all of them you can:

- You put all file list from `tarfile.tar` into `tar.txt`

  ```
  tar -tvf tarfile.tar > tar.txt
  ```
- Now `tar.txt` has the whole list of files in `tarfile.tar`
  and you can leave only the files you want to restore or with head...

  ```
  head -n50 tar.txt > tar2.txt
  ```

You can put these lines into a file

```sh
cat tar.txt|while read line
do
   tar -xvf tarfile.tar ${line}
done
```

Or the complete script file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" = "" || "$2" = "" ]]
   then
   echo ""
   echo "Uso: untar-list.sh tarfile.tar listfile.txt"
   echo ""
   exit 1
fi

tarfile=$1
file=$2

if [[ ! -f ${tarfile} ]]
   then
   echo ""
   echo "Archivo ${tarfile} no existe"
   echo ""
   exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f ${file} ]]
   then
   echo ""
   echo "Archivo ${file} no existe"
   echo ""
   exit 1
fi

cat ${file}|while read line
do
  tar -xvf ${tarfile} ${line}
done

echo ""
echo "Finalizado"
echo ""
```

And that's all

Comment: That has to be painfully slow to call the tar command in a loop. It reads the the whole file each time, right?

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try this myself, but how about this:

```
tar xvf archive.tar | head -n50
```

Tar outputs a line to STDOUT for each file extracted, then the `head` command will kill the pipe after 50 lines. Upon the pipe dying, I'd expect the tar to die too.

Comment: Sorry, that should of course been a `head`. Let me change my answer.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I fear that due to the pipe buffer, `tar` may extract more than 50 files before it's SIGPIPEd, and in particular it may extract the last, incomplete file.