# Copy a file from nested tar.gz file

Tags: tar, archive

I have a situation where I want to extract a file from nested tar.gz. The structure of .tar.gz is as

- test.tar.gz

  - data1

    - data2

      - data3

        - test2.tar.gz

          - data4

            - data5

              - **test.log**

I want to extract only ***test.log*** file from the **test.tar.gz** file. 
I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61461/how-to-extract-specific-files-from-tar-gz) post with which we can extract file of tar.gz but not in nested levels.

I am adding output of tar tfz data1.tar.gz The folder structure might be a bit different as entered the above structure manually.

```
data1/.
data1/META.json
data1/TEMP
data1/TEMP/temp-2
data1/TEMP/temp-2/1-chksum.txt
data1/TEMP/temp-2/1
data1/TEMP/temp-2/1/otherfiles
data1/TEMP/temp-2/1/otherfiles/2016_06_24.tar.gz
```

So the **test.log** file is present within a nested folder inside **2016_06_24.tar.gz**

Comment: Can you post the real output of `tar tfz test.tar.gz` because your "nested" picture doesn't make things too clear.  Edit the question with the output.

Comment: do I understand your diagram correctly to mean that the data4 directory is a member of the test2.tar.gz archive?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that data4 & etc are members of the compressed test2.tar.gz archive, and using [GNU tar's](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Option-Summary.html#SEC42) --strip-components option:

```
tar xzOf ./test.tar.gz data1/data2/data3/test2.tar.gz | \
  tar xzf - --strip-components=2 data4/data5/test.log
```

... which tells the first `tar` to extract the nested compressed tar file to stdout, then tells the second `tar` to take that inputted file and extract only the data4/data5/test.log file, stripping the first two components out. That will drop the test.log file in your current directory. If you do not have GNU tar, simply remove the --strip-components option, and the file will be extracted with the path that it was archived with.

Comment: The `--strip-components=2` I think makes this the better answer. `-f -` is unnecessary, but I suppose that's just stylistic preference, but I must question your two different CLI switch styles (`-x -z -O -f` in the first case, `xzf` in the second)

Comment: You should also probably mention that `--strip-components` is a feature of GNU tar, and may not be found on all POSIX tar implementations

Comment: The Q was tagged Linux, so I made a bit of an assumption.

Comment: does it have to be `-x -z -O -f` or does `xzOf` also work?