# Extracting specific file(s) from tar compressed directory?

Tags: tar

When you extract a individual file from a `tar` compressed directory    ([How to extract specific file(s) from tar.gz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61461/how-to-extract-specific-files-from-tar-gz)) does a copy of this file remain compressed or is it completely removed from the directory?

For example:

```
$ tar -zxvf mydir.tar.gz file1.txt
```

Will `file1.txt` remain stored in the `mydir.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the tar file, whether compressed or not, is not modified.

There is no "tar compressed directory". There may be a compressed tar file containing the content of zero or more directories.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test shows that the file remains within the archive, even after a copy is extracted from it.

*contents of tarball*

```
$ tar ztvf somedir.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x vagrant/vagrant   0 2018-08-08 00:33 somedir/
-rw-rw-r-- vagrant/vagrant   6 2018-08-08 00:33 somedir/file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- vagrant/vagrant   6 2018-08-08 00:33 somedir/file1.txt
```

*size of file, 181 bytes*

```
$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 181 Aug  8 00:33 somedir.tar.gz
```

*extract a file from tarball*

```
$ tar zxvf somedir.tar.gz somedir/file1.txt
somedir/file1.txt
```

*after extracting a file*

```
$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug  8 00:35 somedir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  181 Aug  8 00:33 somedir.tar.gz
```

Size of tarball remains 181 bytes throughout.